# Calculate height of multiline text when writing

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

Using PDPageContentStream I am writing a text like this:

```java
stream.beginText();
stream.newLineAtOffset(400, 400);
stream.setFont(myFont, 10);
stream.setLeading(11.5f);
stream.showText("First line.");
stream.newLine();
stream.showText("Second line.");
stream.setFont(myFontBold, 10);
stream.setLeading(15f);
stream.newLine();
stream.showText("Final line. (bold)");
stream.endText();
```

So it is like

- line 1: leading 11.5, myFont, size 10
- line 2: leading 11.5, myFont, size 10
- line 3: leading 15, myFontBold, size 10

I have these lines in a list. But when I try to calculate the total height so I can draw a box around them, I can't get it to be correct.

I've tried summing all the leadings which is wrong. I have tried summing all the leadings and then the font bounding box height, but it is a little too high. I have also tried character cap height but it is wrong.

I did the bounding box thing like

```java
total += (font.getBoundingBox().getHeight() / 1000.0f) * fontSize;
total += leading;
```

for each line.

Comment: *"I've tried summing all the leadings which is wrong."* - Why is that wrong? You at least need to calculate with the leadings alone to determine the _baseline_ coordinates for your text lines. For the top line you then have to add something like the font ascent, for the last line the font descent. Unfortunately for some fonts the ascent or descent number are incorrect...

Comment: @mkl Hello, I have no knowledge in typography. When I sum all the leadings, it is too short. I am using Arial.

Comment: You should have a look at the DrawPrintTextLocations.java example, the calculation of the cyan rectangles may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you, but it doesn't use PDPageContentStream which my entire code is based on. Also it looks like it draws for each letter/glyph but I just want a box around a paragraph of text

Comment: You would have to get the rendering of each glyph, then take the highest / lowest ascent / descent.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr It doesn't have to be that exact. I just need the height of each row and the spacing between rows. It does not matter if say the row only contains 'x' but the height is calculated as 'H'. I just need the height of the row, not the individual letters

Comment: Then calculate the height of "H" by rendering the glyph. And the descent of "g".

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I'm trying to calculate the height of the text that PDFBox will draw. It also uses leading. I'm sorry I just know nothing about typography and simply want to draw a border around some text (with fixed width).. There's just so many measurements, bounding box, cap height, leading, etc etc. I don't get why it's this hard honestly

Comment: *"I'm trying to calculate the height of the text that PDFBox will draw."* - Here you're subject to a misunderstanding. PDFBox does _not_ draw the text. It merely stores your instructions (move there - set font and font size - set leading - show text ...) in PDF syntax  into the content stream. Thus, PDFBox does _not_ automatically know top or bottom position of the letters shown by some viewer eventually executing those instructions.

Comment: I understand. By the way I solved my problem. My algorithm is basically `((capHeightOfFirstLine/1000f)*fontSize) + leading of each line`. It seems to be correct. Edit: never mind, it does not work in all cases....

Comment: *"It seems to be correct."* - Hhmmm, that seems to ignore the descent of the final line. As your example last line `"Final line. (bold)"` has no descenders, this probably shouldn't surprise. ;)

Comment: Oh it could be, I will check that thank you very much

Comment: @mkl I got it to work thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm for calculating the height of a paragraph is the following:

```
float firstLineCapHeight = (firstLineFont.getFontDescriptor().getCapHeight() / 1000f) * firstLineFontSize;

// this value is negative
float lastLineDescent = (lastLineFont.getFontDescriptor().getDescent() / 1000f) * lastLineFontSize;

float height = firstLineCapHeight + leadingOfAllLinesExceptFirst - lastLineDescent;
```

If the first or last line has multiple fonts or font sizes you will have to find the largest one.

*Depending on the alphabet you can also add the first line ascent but that is not needed in my case.*